# Why do I get this â‚¬ Â£ With Currency's?

Tags: php, meta-tags

Im using an Opencart site

http://www.lutari.net

Where ever there is a currency symbol for the Euro or British Pound. Im Getting Little Â Symbols

I tried putting

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

At the top of page, But then I get PHP errors, Which is odd.

I found this in the index code.

```
// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$response->setCompression($config->get('config_compression'));
$registry->set('response', $response);
```

Which according to some research looks correct, But doesnt work.

Does anyone know how else I can get rid of the weird symbols?

Comment: charset can also be set via php headers / .htaccess in apache etc., e.g. header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: It seems to be working fine now. Did you finally fix it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Currency symbols are embedded by using `&#333;` like codes.

Like euro symbol is by code: `&#8364;`

[Check this for symbols](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/euro.html)

And one more thing use google to search for symbols for currencies

Comment: In the database it was had the symbols so I deleted them and it worked.